# Проверка radio с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Не получается сделать проверку радио с помощью Явы...

```
<form action="/social/system/form.php" method="post" id="registration">
            <table>
                <tr><td><i class="fa fa-male"></i><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />
                                  <i class="fa fa-female"></i><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /></td>
                <td><span id="radioerr"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="registration" value="Зарегистрироваться" onClick="return Register(this.form)" />
  </form>
```

Код явы..

```
    function Register(data) {
    var inp = document.getElementsByName('sex');

    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
        if (inp[i].type == "radio" && inp[i].checked) {
            return true
        } else {
            document.getElementById( 'radioerr' ).innerHTML="* выберите Ваш пол!";
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
```

Проблема в том что скрипт проверяет только первый радио второго для него не существует.

Answer (score 3):

то, что находится в `else`, надо убрать за пределы цикла, иначе, если первый элемент не выбран, тут же выполняется else , и цикл прерывается

```
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
      if (inp[i].type == "radio" && inp[i].checked) {
          return true
      }
  }
  document.getElementById( 'radioerr' ).innerHTML="* выберите Ваш пол!";
  return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
function Register(data) {
      var inp = document.getElementsByName('sex');

      for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
        var radio = inp[i];
        if (radio.type == "radio" && radio.checked) {
            return true
        } else {
            document.getElementById( 'radioerr' ).innerHTML="* выберите Ваш   пол!";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Во-первых, нет, во-вторых, а в чём разница по сравнению с кодом из вопроса?

Comment: Виноват( такое бы сработало в случае возврата последнего элемента. А я видимо невнимательно прочитал вопрос:)